# Запись из регистра в переменную в MIPS

Tags: ассемблер, mips

Как в MIPS внести значение регистра $f0 в переменную a? Значение в регистр попадает из консольного ввода syscall

```
.data
  a: .double 0
.text
.globl main
main:
  li $v0, 7
  syscall
  #здесь хочу внести значение из $f0 в переменную a
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел как:

```
s.d регистр переменная
```

и может быть полезным запись из переменной в регистр:

```
l.d регистр переменная
```

это работает для типов double, для float надо d заменить на s